# Should this be an ANOVA or a MANOVA?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, manova, social-science

I'm fairly new to statistics and am struggling to figure out whether I should be using ANOVA or MANOVA for my research design:

Participants will watch a performance together in one of three different conditions (online, offline, mixed-mode) and after the performance will report on a) how socially bonded they feel, and in turn b) willingness to share money with one another.

So, three independent variables and two (correlated) dependent variables. The dependent variables are measured on a scale of 1-5 and 1-3.

I have received a lot of mixed information about whether I should do an ANOVA or MANOVA, so any input from knowledgeable people would be very very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks rather more like MANOVA, as your response is a vector. MANOVA
ordinarily assumes normal distribution and same covariance matrix of the responses, which are assumed independent. All three assumptions may be more than your application warrants, particularly the independence: you mention that participants watch a performance "together", which suggests their reactions might interact.